# How to use Curl to post data to a script and save the file that is returned

Tags: php, curl, ssh

Hi I'm trying to use curl from the command line to submit a form and save the file that the form forces you to download normally when you use a browser. The form is on this page:

http://dove.cccbr.org.uk/downloads.php

Its the dove.txt file I want to download. As you can see in a browser you check the copyright notice check box and then click the dove.txt button and the file starts downloading.

Here's how I've tried to do it with curl:

```
curl -d "copyright=agree&download=dove.txt" -o dove.txt http://dove.cccbr.org.uk/downloads.php
```

This saves a file but it just has an error message in it

DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
tml>
itle>406 Not Acceptable
head>
1>Not Acceptable

> An appropriate representation of the requested resource /downloads.php could not be found
>    on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found
>   ror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   body>

I'm sure this is very simple for someone who knows how

Comment: the contents of the error message might be handy to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific site blocks the `curl` user agent string. You can spoof another user agent using the `-A` option, e.g.:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0' …
```